# If row or column size of the table is > 1 then action should be available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a blue table. By hovering over it's cells the user makes visible two red buttons: one to delete columns and one to delete rows.

What I need to do is prevent "deleting" buttons from appearing if only one row is left or one column is left:

[image]
[image]

At first I try to find the lenght of rows and columns:

```
var rowCount = $('.my-table tr').length;
var columnCount = $(".my-table > tr:first > td").length;
```

Then I make an if statement:

```
if rowCount > 1 and columnCount > 1 {}
```

but if I put the code that should hide/show red buttons on hover over the blue cell inside the if statement - it does not work:

```
var rowCount = $('.my-table tr').length;
var columnCount = $(".my-table > tr:first > td").length;

if rowCount > 1 and columnCount > 1 {

$(document).on('mouseover','.my-table tr td',function(){
     var columnDelIndex = $("td", $(this).closest("table")).index(this);
   var col_num = $('.my-table tr:first > td').length;   
   $($('.del-column-td')).addClass('hide');
   $($('.del-row-td')).addClass('hide');  
   $($('.del-column-td')[parseInt(columnDelIndex%col_num)]).removeClass('hide');
   $($('.del-row-td')[parseInt(columnDelIndex/col_num)]).removeClass('hide');  
});
}
```

How should I combine this code with the if statement to make it work?

Here is [my working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/gqp5Lj2q/7/) where I am trying to implement this. The if statement is commented out in order to show how everything works.

Comment: You need to set the `rowCount` and `columnCount` variables inside the function. Otherwise they won't change when you add and remove rows or columns.

Comment: Where is the `if` statement?

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable. And don't comment out the code that causes the problem.

Comment: Side note: `$($('.del-column-td'))` this is pointless as the inner call is already going to create a jQuery object, the outer call is just going to create a new one with the same element collection. As for the last two calls in your example you can just use [`eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get an element at a specified index within the collection.

Comment: @Barmar, I have copied the whole piece of code under question here.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, thank you, I will try to put these adjustments in my code.

Comment: @mayua You didn't copy the HTML, you didn't create an executable snippet.

Comment: The `if` statement needs to be inside the function.

Comment: thank you for the advice, I will take it into account. As for the html, the code is too huge to copy it here. The layout is a bit complex and I would not like to cover ten pages in code here. So I thought that it might be more comfortable to outsource the whole piece of code. I know this is not the best solution, but I decided that it is the optimal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/j4n4p0ns/1/

I've put the var rowCount and columnCount as global variable, setting them with the initial number of rows and cols, then when you delete/add them you'll change them accordingly.

here is the code:

```
var rowCount = $('.my-table tr').length;
var columnCount = $(".my-table tr:first > td").length;

// adding new column by clicking the add button on the right
$('.addColumnChild').click(function() {
  $('.my-table tr').each(function() {
    $(this).append(`<td></td>`);
  })
  columnCount++; //here you will increment the column count
});

// adding new cell to the table with column delete buttons

$('.addColumnChild').click(function() {
  $('.del-column tr').each(function() {
    $('.del-column tr').append(`<td class="del del-column-td">${$('.del-column-td').html()}</td>`);
  })
});

// adding new row by clicking the add button on the bottom

$('.addRowChild').click(function() {
  $('.my-table tbody').append(`<tr>${$('.default-row').html()}</tr>`);
  rowCount++;
});

// adding new cell to the table with row delete buttons

$('.addRowChild').click(function() {
  $('.table-del tbody').append(`<tr>${$('.del-row-tr').html()}</tr>`);
});

// finding nearest row to the del button and on click deleting it with the button itself

$('.table-del').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var trIndex = $("tr", $(this).closest("table")).index(this);
  $($('.my-table tr')[trIndex]).remove()
  $(this).remove();
  rowCount--;  //decrease the row count...
})

// finding nearest column to the dell button and on click deleting it with the button itself

$('.del-column').on('click', 'td', function() {
  var index = this.cellIndex;

  $('.my-table').find('tr').each(function() {
    this.removeChild(this.cells[index]);
  });
  $(this).remove();
  columnCount--;
});

// showing/hiding delete buttons when hovering over a particular cell in the main table  


$(document).on('mouseover','.my-table tr td',function(){
     var columnDelIndex = $("td", $(this).closest("table")).index(this);
   var col_num = $('.my-table tr:first > td').length;   
   $($('.del-column-td')).addClass('hide');
   $($('.del-row-td')).addClass('hide');  
   $($('.del-column-td')   
if(columnCount>1){
   $($('.del-column-td')[parseInt(columnDelIndex%col_num)]).removeClass('hide');
   }
   if(rowCount>1){
   $($('.del-row-td')[parseInt(columnDelIndex/col_num)]).removeClass('hide');  
   }    
});


// preventing delete buttons diappear when hovering over them

var colTimer, rowTimer;
$(document).on('mouseleave','.my-table',function(){ 
   colTimer = setTimeout(function() {
     $('.del-column-td').addClass('hide');
   }, 1000);

     rowTimer = setTimeout(function() {
     $('.del-row-td').addClass('hide');
   }, 1000);
});

$(document).on('mouseover','.del-column-td',function(){
    clearTimeout(colTimer);
});

$(document).on('mouseleave','.del-column-td',function(){    
  $('.del-column-td').addClass('hide');
});

$(document).on('mouseover','.del-row-td',function(){
    clearTimeout(rowTimer);
});

$(document).on('mouseleave','.del-row-td',function(){   
   $('.del-row-td').addClass('hide');

});
```

Comment: thank you for this solution! There is one slight issue. When there is one row: both buttons are not shown. But the top red button should be shown if there is one row but more than 1 columns in it. Can this be solved somehow? I guess the complexity is that 1 piece of code is used to hide/show these buttons and so it will be hard to de-synchronize it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify things a bit.

Change this:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.my-table tr td',function(){
   var columnDelIndex = $("td", $(this).closest("table")).index(this);
   var col_num = $('.my-table tr:first > td').length;   

   $($('.del-column-td')).addClass('hide');
   $($('.del-row-td')).addClass('hide');  
   $($('.del-column-td')[parseInt(columnDelIndex%col_num)]).removeClass('hide');
   $($('.del-row-td')[parseInt(columnDelIndex/col_num)]).removeClass('hide');  
});
```

… to this:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.my-table tr td',function(){
  var col = $(this).index(),           //current column
      row = $(this).parent().index();  //current row

   $('.del-column-td').addClass('hide');
   $('.del-row-td').addClass('hide');  

   $('.del-column-td').eq(col).removeClass('hide');
   $('.del-row-td').eq(row).removeClass('hide');  
});
```

You can then prevent the row delete button from showing if the table has only one row:

```
if($('.my-table tr').length > 1) {
  $('.del-row-td').eq(row).removeClass('hide');  
}
```

And you can prevent the column delete button from showing if the table has no `td` that's a 2nd child of its parent:

```
 if($('.my-table td:nth-child(2)').length) {
   $('.del-column-td').eq(col).removeClass('hide');
 }
```

Complete function:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.my-table tr td', function() {
  var col = $(this).index(),
      row = $(this).parent().index();

  $('.del-column-td').addClass('hide');
  $('.del-row-td').addClass('hide');

  if ($('.my-table td:nth-child(2)').length) {
    $('.del-column-td').eq(col).removeClass('hide');
  }

  if ($('.my-table tr').length > 1) {
    $('.del-row-td').eq(row).removeClass('hide');
  }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqae9wm2/)**

Comment: thank you for such an elegant solution! I can hardly miss this chance and ask a bit more of your help with my task. When I add new columns with the yellow button on the right - it strangely adds sometimes one and sometimes two blue cells on the place where red "delete" buttons should be. Do you know by any chance why is it doing so and how it can be corrected? (Here is the picture: https://imgur.com/Vplxlge)

Comment: Add this code at the beginning of your second `addColumnChild` click event:  `$('.del-column-td').addClass('hide');`

Comment: Then add the `hide` class to the append statement in the same event.

Comment: great, thank you! I know that I am asking too much, but maybe you will have an opportunity to help me one more time. I do not know why, but when I delete the first row and then try to add a new one - the model behaves strangely and refuses to add new rows. Maybe this is due to the incorrect positioning of the button that adds columns. For example, when I add so many columns that they reach the edge of the window - this button jumps under the main table...

Comment: Hard to tell, and I may not have a chance to look at it until next week.

Comment: I see what causes it.  If you delete the first row, `$('.del-row-tr').html()` is undefined.

Comment: You can fix it by changing the first `addRowChild` click event to:  `$('.my-table tbody').append(`<tr>${$('.my-table tr:first').html()}</tr>`);`

Comment: it works perfectly, thank you! Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1):

Try this put row and column checks in different if statements:

```
var rowCount;
var columnCount;

$(document).on('mouseover','.my-table tr td',function(){
rowCount = $('.my-table tr').length;
columnCount = $(".my-table tr:first > td").length;
var columnDelIndex = $("td", $(this).closest("table")).index(this);
var col_num = $('.my-table tr:first > td').length;   

    if(rowCount > 1) {
    $($('.del-row-td')).addClass('hide');  
    $($('.del-row-td')[parseInt(columnDelIndex/col_num)]).removeClass('hide');
 }
 if(columnCount > 1 ){
    $($('.del-column-td')).addClass('hide');
    $($('.del-column-td')[parseInt(columnDelIndex%col_num)]).removeClass('hide');
 }
});
```